# How to set single image for QWidget (all forms background in Qt app)?

Tags: css, qt

this is my `style.qss` and in this I set Qwidget:

```
/*QMainWindow*/ QWidget
{
        background-image: url(:/myImg/pic/12.png);
}
```

I have several forms in my app but just all widget get background image like my buttons, group boxes and .... except the main UI. the main ui is just white and does not get image.
**Note: the Main window is get the image for background but the other pages background is just white and not changed.**
this the whole of my css:

```
/*  ALL      */
*{
    border:none;
    font:10pt "Ubuntu";
        color:white;

}
/*========================================*/
/*     QScrollBar       */
QScrollBar:vertical {
border: none;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
width: 40px;
margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
stop: 0 rgba(183, 210, 192, 255), stop: 0.5 rgba(105, 165, 5, 255), stop:1 rgba(203, 225, 0, 255));
min-height: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
stop: 0 rgba(183, 210, 192, 255), stop: 0.5 rgba(105, 165, 5, 255), stop:1 rgba(203, 225, 0, 255));
height: 20px;
subcontrol-position: bottom;
subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
stop: 0 rgba(183, 210, 192, 255), stop: 0.5 rgba(105, 165, 5, 255), stop:1 rgba(203, 225, 0, 255));
height: 20px;
subcontrol-position: top;
subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
/*========================================*/
/*     QWidget - QDialog       */
/*QMainWindow*/ QWidget/*[win="true"]*/
{
        background-image: url(:/myImg/pic/12.png);
}
/*QGroupBox
{
        background-color:rgb(67,67,67);
        border: 1px solid gray;
        border-radius: 9px;
        margin-top: 1em;
}*/




*[taskbox=\"true\"] ,#gbf,#gbfp,#gbborder,#gbusr,#gbauth, #gbsysinfo ,#gbsysinfo2
{
         border: 1px solid gray;
         border-radius: 9px;
         margin-top: 1em;
}
#gbMessage
{
        background-color:rgb(250,250,250);
}


QGroupBox::title
{
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
        subcontrol-position: top center; /* position at the top center */
        /*padding: 3px 3px;*/

}
#gbtransparent
{
    background:transparent;
}
#gbKB
{
    background-color:rgb(60,60,60);
}
#gbKB QPushButton
{
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.0239234, y1:0.966, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(155, 152, 152, 255));
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-width:60px;
    min-height:60px;
    font:18px;
}
#gbMessage
{
    background-color: rgb(222, 219, 219);
}
/*==================================*/
QMessageBox
{
    font:14px;
}
QMessageBox QPushButton{font:14pt;}
/*========================================*/
/*  Button  */

QPushButton[mandatoryField="true"] 
{
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-width:60px;
    min-height:60px; 
}
/*#btnBack
{
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:0.682, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0.142857 rgba(220, 0, 22, 255), stop:0.980296 rgba(216, 74, 73, 255), stop:1 rgba(217, 73, 73, 255));
    border: none;
        border-radius:30px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
        font:18pt "Ubuntu" Bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-width:30px;
    min-height:30px;

}*/


#Functions QPushButton
{
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:0.682, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0.142857 rgba(220, 0, 22, 255), stop:0.980296 rgba(216, 74, 73, 255), stop:1 rgba(217, 73, 73, 255));
    border:none ;
    color:white;
}
/*===================*/
/*   QLabel     */

#lbl
{
    font:28px "Ubuntu" Bold;
    color:white;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
#lblText
{
    border:none ;
    color:black;
    font:16px "Ubuntu" Bold;

}
#lblFn
{
    background-color:/* qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:0.682, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0.142857 rgba(220, 0, 22, 255), stop:0.980296 rgba(216, 74, 73, 255), stop:1 rgba(217, 73, 73, 255));*/
qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:0.994646, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:0.00478469 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:0.0382775 rgba(11, 62, 9, 255), stop:0.0478469 rgba(26, 137, 184, 255), stop:0.976077 rgba(57, 85, 124, 251), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));
    border:none ;
    color:white;
    font:18px;
    qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;

}
/*==================================*/
/*        QLINEDIT       */
QLineEdit
{
    color:black;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size:16px Bold;
    color: Black;
        min-height: 45px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border-color: gray;
}
QLineEdit:hover
{
    border-color: #D2691E;
    border-radius:5px;
}
/*==================*/
/*           QCombobox     */
QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    /*background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #797979, stop:0.48 #696969, stop:0.52 #5e5e5e, stop:1 #4f4f4f);
    padding: 1px 23px 1px 3px;*/
    background:rgb(70,70,70);
    min-width: 6em;
    color: #ffffff;
}
QComboBox::drop-down {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 20px;

    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
QComboBox::down-arrow {
     image: url(:/myImg/pic/down-arrow.png);
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView{
    background-color: #4f4f4f;
    color: white;
    font:18px;
    selection-background-color: #999999;
    selection-color: #4f4f4f;
}
/*QComboBox{
        background-color: rgb(70,70,70);
        border-color:white;
        color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
        min-height:30px;
    min-width:70px;
    text-align:center;
}
QComboBox::drop-down
{
    border-width:1px;
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    min-width: 45px;
    font:14px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
QComboBox::drop-down {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: center right;
    font:16px;


}
QComboBox::down-arrow
{
    image: url(:/myImg/pic/down-arrow.png) 100px 200px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;

}*/
/*QComboBox{
    background-color: rgb(70,70,70);
    color: white;
    padding: 1px;

    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;

}
QComboBox::drop-down
{
    border-width:1px;
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 45px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
QComboBox::down-arrow
{
    image: url(:/myImg/pic/down-arrow.png) 100px 200px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;

}*/
/*===================================*/
/*               QCheckBox               */
QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked
{
    image: url(:/myImg/pic/chkBox.png);
}
QCheckBox::indicator:checked
{
    image: url(:/myImg/pic/tick.png);
}
QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked
{
    image: url(:/myImg/pic/chkBox.png);
}
QRadioButton::indicator:checked
{
    image: url(:/myImg/pic/tick.png);
}
/*==================================*/
/*            QFrame   */
QFrame
{
    background:transparent;
}
#FrameButton QPushButton
{
    text-align: left;
        padding-top:150px;
    color:white;
}
/*====================================*/
/*             QTableView             */
QTableView
{
    gridline-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.5, x2:1, y2:0.5, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop: 0.3 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop: 0.7 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-color:white;

}
QTableView::item
{
    color:gray;
    text-align:center;
}
QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1,
                                      stop:0 #616161, stop: 0.5 #505050,
                                      stop: 0.6 #434343, stop:1 #656565);
    color: white;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}
/*=============================================
==================================================
=================================================*/
```

Comment: Did you do http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop for certain widget or http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop for the entire application? By setting the stylesheet for the widget you only alter it and its children but by setting the stylesheet for the app you have more global stylesheet for all UI.

Comment: I told this is `style.qss`. it is my global stylesheet. all of them apply on my application. my problem is just background image for all UI.